# How to call the method in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I rewrote many times, but this code just doesn't work:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Greeting : NSObject
- (void)sayHello;
@end
@implementation Greeting
- (void)sayHello {
   NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
}
@end
int main(){
   Greeting *v= [[Greeting alloc]init];
[v sayHello];
}
```

Comment: Yes, that’s how methods are called. Are you sure `main` is getting called at all? Try adding a breakpoint or log statement inside `main` and make sure it’s getting called.

Comment: What kind of target is this? macOS command line?

Comment: There's no errors with the code as written. You probably need to compile and execute it correctly. Can you provide more details about how you're trying to compile and run the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you name your file hw.m and type this into the command line in Terminal (mac) it should work (does here):

```
clang hw.m -framework Foundation -o hw && ./hw
```